# How do I install the USB drivers for Bigtreetech's SKR Mini E3 v1.2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, skr-mini-e3, bigtreetech

I want to install the USB drivers for the BIGTREETECH SKR Mini E3 v1.2 from the [GitHub](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware?spm=a2g0s.imconversation.0.0.1f8f3e5fTFicN0) page but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go on youtube in the channel of teaching tech. Make a search about the board Bigtreetech SKR mini E3 v1.2 and I found this link that could help you too https://www.thingiverse.com/groups/ender3/forums/general/topic:40751